# Why does enabling the administration port in WebLogic cause transaction timeout errors?

Tags: transactions, weblogic, admin

We're using WebLogic 12.1.1. We have a Java client application that makes a call to an EJB that handles the business logic within a transaction, but on some requests, calls to another EJB service for additional data. This service EJB happens completely without transactions (TransactionAttribute.NOT_SUPPORTED).

With this setup, we have an old development environment where this sequence of calls works, and now a new development environment where this sequence of calls fails with a javax.transaction.SystemException ("Timeout during commit processing"). I've carefully gone through the differences between the old and new environments and the only difference is that in the new environment, the domain's Administration Port is turned on. Indeed, when I enable the Administration Port in the old environment, I get the same timeout exception.

**So my question is this: Why does enabling the administration port in a WebLogic domain cause changes in transaction behavior?**